# How to open image closeup view, on onclick of image in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have one image view, I set the image on it. I want to open closeup view of that image by onclick of that image. 
How we can achieve this? any idea

Comment: What do you mean by image close up view? Do you mean when you select image which is the thumbnail image and when you select that you want to open original image in other view which displays full image?

Comment: yes.. you are talking right. just I want to open that image full view like popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly do this:

```
imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Another thing is add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate in .h of yourViewController

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Now Add UITapGestureRecognizer in imageView.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageTap:)];
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tap.delegate = self;
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [tap release];

// handle method
- (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
   // your closeup view here on image click
   UIImageView *imgPopView = [UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
   // Add image in imgPopView
   [self.view addSubView:imgPopView];

   // instantaneously make the image view small (scaled to 1% of its actual size)
   imgPopView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
    // animate it to the identity transform (100% scale)
    iimgPopView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished){
    // if you want to do something once the animation finishes, put it here
  }];

}
```

Comment: just add a new subview with the image on it when the image is clicked. there are different possibilities to make a "close up".

Comment: hey thanks for solution but I got one error message for image is "Property 'transform' not found on object of type 'Uimage *'"  on following lines 
imgPopView.image.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
imgPopView.image.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

Comment: I got following error:  
assigning 'CAT Transform 3D' (aka 'struct CATransfrom3D') from incompatable type 'CGAffineTransform'
on following line
 imgPopView.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
 imgPopView.layer.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

Comment: mgPopView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01);
      [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        // animate it to the identity transform (100% scale)
        iimgPopView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
      } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        // if you want to do something once the animation finishes, put it here
      }];

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can do multiple thing to do this

1. Make custom type button over imageView and on button click do whatever you want.
2. Using Touch begin delegate you can identify that where you touch on screen and then check that touch coordinate is of image.
3. Using `GestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below steps.

1. Add tap gesture on `UIImageView` like below.

   UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleImageTap:)];
   tap.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
   tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
   tap.delegate = self;
   [imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
   [tap release];

   // handle method

   - (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
     // your closeup view here on image click
     }
2. Create one class of `UIViewController`. Take `UIImageView` object inside it and connect it to XIB file using IBOutlet and also create UIImage object as property.
3. Create UIViewController object in function `- (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer` and set current object or original from path image path to image property of controller.
4. Set property image to UIImageView's image property in `viewDidLoad` method of the controller class.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer given by Prince is Correct.. You have to animation to ImageView by changing the ImageView Frame in the method

```
- (void) handleImageTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
// your closeup view here on image click
[yourImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];

}
```

You can add animations using `CATransition` to get like a popUp.